# How to log the Console logs into the file using log4js

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, log4js-node

I want to log the console logs whether the expect failing or any exception coming into the log file. How can i do that without using try and catch.
In LOG4j for java there is rootlogger which automatically logs all the system information logs into the file. Can same be done for log4JS for javascript

```
log4js.configure({
  appenders: [
    {
      type: "clustered",
      appenders: [
        {
          type: "dateFile",
          filename: "log/access.log",
          pattern: "-yyyy-MM-dd",
          category: "http"
        },
        {
          type: "file",
          filename: "log/app.log",
          maxLogSize: 10485760,
          numBackups: 3
        },
        {
          type: "logLevelFilter",
          level: "ERROR",
          appender: {
            type: "file",
            filename: "log/errors.log"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *override* the default `console.log` functions to point to your logger e.g.

```
const logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');
console.log = (msg) => logger.trace(msg);
```

You can do similar things for other functions e.g. `console.debug` etc.

That said. You would be better off calling `logger` explicitly.

Comment: So using console.log = (msg) => logger.trace(msg)
it will print whatever we are printing
like console.log("My Name")
but what about the stacktrace which is not part of the script but thrown by the driver/jasmine